# How to disable admin flyout menus?

Tags: wp-admin, javascript, admin-menu

Seriously, I hate flyout menus with a passion, and now they're popping up all over the place in the admin screen. (They are particularly heinous when you use the blue admin theme, because they add a dark arrow. Eye dirt.)

How do I disable the flyout menu? They add zero functionality and usability to my workflow.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a workarround but here you go:

```
function remove_flyout() {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
        .js #adminmenu .wp-submenu.sub-open {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'remove_flyout');
```

Put it in your functions.php

Comment: Hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Aaron Campbell [wrote a gist](https://gist.github.com/1281508) to expand all menus all the time. The dev chat today also indicated some issues in the blue theme.

For more discussion, see [Admin menu doesn't expand/collapse in 3.3 beta 1. Why?](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/admin-menu-doesnt-expandcollapse-in-33-beta-1-why) in the Support forums.

Comment: I don't want them expanded all the time. I have no issues with the accordion effect. It's the stupid popup menu that I don't want. Thanks for the link though

Comment: These new fly out menus are driving me crazy to. Seems unprofessional aswell.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided is not working in modern version, but I've finally found how to fix it in a new one, just add

```
#adminmenuwrap {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

via custom css plugin or browser add-on and flyouts both on :hover and :active will be hidden