# Disable flyout (popup) menus in backend

Tags: wp-admin, javascript, admin-menu

In wp-admin backend, if I hover my mouse over a menu at the left, it popups with submenus. I am absolutely able to click the menu myself, if I want the submenus to show up. So I am searching a way to disable this useless feature, but I cant find out how.

This question was already asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30899/how-to-disable-admin-flyout-menus/282582#282582), but moderators keep deleting my comments, so unfortunately, I am forced to make a new one

I've found, that `<a>` element, that represents a menu, has an `aria-haspopup="true"` property, so I'm thinking about a way to set it in all menus to "false", or just edit a javascript that uses this property, but I can't find out how to do it yet.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have found the solution in modern version of wordpress, to disable flyouts a custom CSS of

```
#adminmenuwrap {
overflow: hidden;
}
```

should be added. I've answered in the old theme as well, so if moderators will not delete my answer there again, this topic is redundant